# How to plot RS chart using Matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing, rs

I am working with some video data and I expected to see some self similarity when plotting the RS chart, instead I got zigzagy lines. I would like some of you to check my code segment & tell me if I did something wrong in it.
The video file has 114 frames & I have a seperate function that computes the R over sigma and returns that value plus the no of pixels.

```
points=zeros(7,5,1);
RS=zeros(7,5,1);
for l=1:7
    x= floor(rand()*240);
    y=floor(rand()*320);
im_frame=image_data(x,y,1,:);
im_frame=im_frame(:);

for i=1:5
        N=floor(length(im_frame)/2^(i-1));
    for j=1:2^(i-1)
        [pt,RSt]=calcRSrange(im_frame((i-1)*N+1:i*N));
        points(l,i) = pt+points(l,i);
        RS(l,i)=RSt+RS(l,i);
    end
    points(l,i)=points(l,i)/j;
    RS(l,i)=RS(l,i)/j;
end
end
log_RS=log(RS);
log_points=log(points);
figure
plot(log_points',log_RS')
xlabel('log no. of pixels')
ylabel('Log RS value')
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Hi. What's a RS chart?

Comment: It refers to a Rescaled range Analysis chart. It is calculated by computing rescaled ranges and dividing each rescaled range by standard deviation of that data's range, hence the name, RS. This statistical technique is used to asses the variability of a given data over time.

Comment: So is it my understanding that you're only supposed to plot discrete points?  Instead of using `plot`, use `stem` or `bar`.

Comment: Actually I need to plot each RS versus the size of the series on a logarithmic scale, and if it is almost a straight line, I should be able to calculate its slope, this is called the Hurst factor.

Comment: Can I ask what is your interpretation of the following code line: x= floor(rand()*240);